Tips for pre-processing long unstructured text?
I'm working on a React-Node project where I'm trying to pre-process some text before passing it to GPT-4 to perform information extraction out of it, the flow of the project is:

User uploads document
OCR is performed on the document and text is produced
Results are organized as an array of objects where each object is a message with 'role' and 'content' keys, where 'content' has the text from each page. And this is used to construct a GPT prompt.
GPT should produce a JSON with keys representing specific information to be extracted out of the text and values containing the extracted information

The issue I am running into is that the data that is going in is too big, some documents are poorly formatted and not split properly. Documents can be part of one of two categories, each category's documents contain different kinds of information, for the sake of the question I'll define the following 2 categories:

Category 1: monetary information regarding different categories
Category 2: categorical information describing different situations and the process for each situation

And usually documents are split where one document exists for each category, in these cases, data is small and doesn't require pre-processing. However, some cases exist where both categories' documents are mashed into one and the data is very large for the token limit available. I should add that when constructing the prompt, the category matters because each category has a different prompt and different output JSON structure.
My question is: what is some generic pre-processing I can do to help lessen the size of the data but not lose semantic relationships? For context, the OCR produces some unreadable symbols that show as "?" and some random symbols. Another thing, is it possible to trim out some sections of the OCR result based on section title? I've been trying to think of how to do this, but different documents have different naming conventions for these sections.
